# In which language the KIS application might have been developed?

Tags: programming-languages

I just went through this link http://www.pcauthority.com.au/Feature/91093,the-tsar-of-antivirus.aspx and found that it's developed using c/c++ and visual studio with a little assembly language support.

As a programmer i just want to know in what programming language the kaspersky internet security User Interface(UI) has been developed?

Might be using QT(coz. of c++)? or using MFC(coz. of visual studio)??

With side tab like thing the UI looks good.

Expecting the answers from expert analysts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PE Editor like [PEiD](http://www.peid.info/) to check the executable for compiler signatures in the PE file header or the names of the DLLs imported by that executable.